# Python pymssql insert error

Tags: pymssql

My table has 24 columns around half of the column in my table are of float datatype. Specified 24 filed, I have truncated the insert statement here.

```
csv_data = csv.reader(file('filename.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('insert into ddreplication (CTX, Mode,...,Max_repl_streams) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', tuple(row))
```

**Error:**

```
File "pymssql.pyx", line 467, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
(pymssql.c:7561)
    pymssql.OperationalError: (8114, 'Error converting data type varchar to float.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL
Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

Im having almost the same code on another script which is running fine without any issues.

**Output of** ***"SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='ddreplication' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION"***

[(u'CTX', u'int'), (u'Mode', u'nvarchar'), (u'Destination', u'nvarchar'), (u'Connection_Host', u'nvarchar'), (u'Enabled', u'nvarchar'), (u'Low_bandwidth_optimization', u'nvarchar'), (u'Replication_encryption', u'nvarchar'), (u'Replication_propagate_retention_lock', u'nvarchar'), (u'Local_fs_status', u'nvarchar'), (u'Connection', u'nvarchar'), (u'State', u'nvarchar'), (u'Error', u'nvarchar'), (u'Network_bytes_to_destination', u'float'), (u'PreComp_bytes_written_to_source', u'float'), (u'PreComp_bytes_sent_to_destination', u'float'), (u'Bytes_after_synthetic_optimization', u'float'), (u'Bytes_after_filtering_by_destination', u'float'), (u'Bytes_after_low_bandwidth_optimization', u'float'), (u'Bytes_after_local_comp', u'float'), (u'PreComp_bytes_remaining', u'float'), (u'Compression_ration', u'float'), (u'Synced_as_of_time', u'nvarchar'), (u'Current_throttle', u'nvarchar'), (u'Max_repl_streams', u'nvarchar')]

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Additionally, you checked that column order in the CSV matches exactly with the column list for the INSERT statement?

Comment: I have attached 2 lines from my datafile.  I have double checked Column order in CSV matches insert statement. I have truncated 2 row data due to space here

19,destination,mtree://dd9500ausprd01.storage.anz/data/col1/oracle-longterm-fromtm,dd9500ausdr01R.storage.anz,yes,disabled,disabled,enabled,enabled,idle since Sat Aug 19 02:33:45,normal,no error,324423376,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N/A,Sat Aug 19 02:33,unlimited (Recovery only),32 (default)

20,source,mtree://d234sdfcom1.storage.com/data/col1/FROMNSDEVMW,....4624454382864,...,3812323071052,0,22.1,Sat Aug 19 02:46,unlimited,32 (default)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the results of `cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='ddreplication' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION"); print(cursor.fetchall())`

Comment: Additionally, please add then function

    def is_float(s):
        try:
            if s is None:
                return False
            f = float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

in your script and post the output of this line, which you kindly insert before the  `cursor.execute` line:

[print(i, is_float(v)) for i,v in enumerate(row)]

Comment: @GordThompson - I have edited my question with the requested info

Comment: @Arminius - Your suggestion helped me to find the culprit within my data.  There is a particular column which was supposed to write some number OR 0, But it was getting written as "N/A" which resulted in an error I mentioned in the question.  Also it helped me to spot another error which happens when I was extracting the original data and creating the csv file.  Last line of my CSV file have some issues.  Now I managed to skip those errors and got my data into MSSQL DB.  Now I will try and fix my code to avoid those errors in first place.  Thanks Arminius

Comment: @Raju glad I could help. Fell into that tar pit myself more than once :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below function helped me to find out the errors on my original data. It give me details such as data type of each of the value that I'm trying to insert and count of values that is getting passed into the insert statement.  Now I managed to override and get data inserted into the db, excluding the problem record.

Now I'm working on fixing my problem record and get it into DB.

def is_float(s):
 try:
  if s is None:
   return False
  f = float(s)
  return True
 except ValueError:
  return False

print (len(row))
 for i,v in enumerate(row):
  print(i, is_float(v),row[i])

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, the troublesome line in your source data contains 'N/A' for the `float` column "Compression_ration", and 'N/A' cannot be parsed to a numeric value. You can replace 'N/A' with `None` to insert a null by changing your query parameters from

```python
tuple(row)
```

to

```python
tuple(None if x == 'N/A' else x for x in row)
```